# How can I use format like this b'\x{:x}'.format(255) to get an hex-bytes output like this b'\xff'?

Tags: python, binary, hex, byte

I want to dynamically create hex-bytes objects like e.g. b'\xff', but get the error

```
SyntaxError: (value error) invalid \x escape at position 0
```

when I try this:

```
b'\x{:x}'.format(255)
```

This

```
r'\x{:x}'.format(255)
```

outputs this

```
'\\xff'
```

but this creates double slashes in my output & the output is not a bytes object.

Is there any way to do this?
hex(255) which leads to '0xff' is not sufficient, I really need to get this output '\xff' as a bytes object.

Comment: Unfortunately not. My problem is that I cannot get the '\x' inside the bytes object..

Comment: bytes(hex(100), 'latin-1') gives me b'0x64' and is the closest I get. 
Unfortunately bytes(chr(100), 'latin-1') gives b'd', but I need b'\x64' as output.
chr() with latin-1 encoding encodes some numbers from 0-255 correctly, but some are not hex..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a `bytes` object by giving it a list of the byte values:

```
>>> bytes([255])
b'\xff'
>>> bytes([1,2,3,4])
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
```

Note that bytes in the printable ASCII range will displays as their ASCII character, but that is only a *display representation* of the `bytes` object.  The byte values are still correct:

```py
>>> x = bytes([1,65,66,67,255])
>>> x
b'\x01ABC\xff'
>>> x[1]
65
>>> x[2]
66
>>> x[3]
67
```

You can print the hex values with `.hex()`:

```
>>> x.hex()
'01414243ff'
>>> x.hex(sep=' ')
'01 41 42 43 ff'
```